# how can I have the different max of several lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want get different max from different list but the problem i get the same max,this is my code ,why problem in this code ,i have got the same max for the first list,what i do change for obtain a result max for different list:

```
def best(contactList_id,ntf_DeliveredCount):
    maxtForEvryDay = []
    yPredMaxForDay = 0
    for day in range(1,8):
        for marge in range(1,5):
            result = predictUsingNewSample([[contactList_id,ntf_DeliveredCount,day,marge]])
            if (result > yPredMaxForDay):
                yPredMaxForDay = 0
                yPredMaxForDay = result
        maxtForEvryDay.append(yPredMaxForDay)
    return maxtForEvryDay   
best(contactList_id = 13.0,ntf_DeliveredCount = 5280.0)


    result:

[1669.16010381]
[1708.32915255]
[1747.49820129]
[1786.66725003]
[1570.05500351]
[1609.22405225]
[1648.39310099]
[1687.56214973]
[1491.60792629]
[1510.11895195]
[1549.28800069]
[1588.45704943]
[1402.21845533]
[1420.73953501]
[1450.18290039]
[1489.35194913]
[1367.15490803]
[1356.21411426]
[1345.27532239]
[1390.24684884]
[1378.1190426]
[1367.17824883]
[1419.23588013]
[1486.78241686]
[1450.21261674]
[1516.04342599]
[1581.87423524]
[1647.7050445]
[array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003]),
 array([1786.66725003])]
```

Comment: What does predictUsingNewSample() do? It runs fine for me if I replace that function for an integer.

Comment: Can you provide an example of return values from the predictUsingNewSample()?

Comment: [1669.16010381]
[1708.32915255]
[1747.49820129]
[1786.66725003]
[1570.05500351]
[1609.22405225]
[1648.39310099]
[1687.56214973]
[1491.60792629]
[1510.11895195]
[1549.28800069]
[1588.45704943]
[1402.21845533]
[1420.73953501]
[1450.18290039]
[1489.35194913]
[1367.15490803]
[1356.21411426]
[1345.27532239]
[1390.24684884]
[1378.1190426]
[1367.17824883]
[1419.23588013]
[1486.78241686]
[1450.21261674]
[1516.04342599]
[1581.87423524]
[1647.7050445]

Comment: 1
[1669.16010381]
[1708.32915255]
[1747.49820129]
[1786.66725003]
2
[1570.05500351]
[1609.22405225]
[1648.39310099]
[1687.56214973]
3
[1491.60792629]
[1510.11895195]
[1549.28800069]
[1588.45704943]
4
[1402.21845533]
[1420.73953501]
[1450.18290039]
[1489.35194913]
5
[1367.15490803]
[1356.21411426]
[1345.27532239]
[1390.24684884]
6
[1378.1190426]
[1367.17824883]
[1419.23588013]
[1486.78241686]
7
[1450.21261674]
[1516.04342599]
[1581.87423524]
[1647.7050445]

Comment: i want get the max for ech list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Comment: for 1:[1786.66725003]

Comment: for 2:1687.56214973] ...

Comment: If I understand correctly and you predictUsingNewSample() returns an array, you cannot compare it to your max value. You will need to get the element out of the array and compare that one to your previous max

Comment: please can you write the correct code

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my fonction predictUsingNewSample(X_test)
 def predictUsingNewSample(X_test):
#print(X_test)
# Load from file
with open("pickle_model.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    pickle_model = pickle.load(file)
    Ypredict = pickle_model.predict(X_test)
    print(Ypredict)
return Ypredict
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def best(contactList_id,ntf_DeliveredCount):
    maxtForEvryDay = []

    for day in range(1,8):
        yPredMaxForDay = 0
        for marge in range(1,5):
            result = predictUsingNewSample([[contactList_id,ntf_DeliveredCount,day,marge]])

            if (result > yPredMaxForDay):
                yPredMaxForDay = result

        maxtForEvryDay.append(yPredMaxForDay)
    return maxtForEvryDay   

best(contactList_id = 13.0,ntf_DeliveredCount = 5280.0)
```

I think the problem actually comes from the fact that you never clean up your yPredMaxForDay variable for each day.